# Carlike robot's localization algorithm in simulation

Tags: navigation, simulation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have been struggling finding the right tutorials for me. Here is what I need to do: I need to simulate AMCL algorithm of a carlike robot using such sensors as odometry, lidar, gyroscope and accelerometer in pure simulation. I have read about RVIZ but the robot is supposed to be carlike, therefore I started looking into turtlebot_simulation tutorials which gave me a dead end because it required indigo version (I am running jade).

I have looked through all beginner/intermediate tutorials, but I just keep hitting a wall. I would really appreciate if someone would give me links/tips to the useful tutorials.

Dont hesitate to ask me more information in case my question is unclear.

**EDIT** Can I simulate IMU data in ROS stage? I have found this [question](http://answers.ros.org/question/52758/fake-imu-for-stage/), but its rather outdated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/230927/carlike-robot%27s-localization-algorithm-in-simulation/) by [murdock](https://answers.ros.org/users/26483/murdock/) on ROS Answers with karma: 75 on 2016-04-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You cannot use rviz on its own for your purpose, since you want to simulate a carlike robot.
rviz is just a visualization.

You have three options for simulating a carlike robot:

1. [not recommended] Write your own simulation model (implement the discrete equations of motion and publish the current state to rviz)
2. Write a gazebo plugin for your carlike robot (this might be more advanced)
3. Use the 2D - simulator [stage](http://wiki.ros.org/stage_ros).

I would prefer option 3 for your task, since stage is able to simulate your carlike motion as well as laser/sonar range sensors. This should be enough for your AMCL task. You can also add noise to your motion model (in the stage config), which is great for your evaluation.

In order to setup stage, your can refer to the following links:

- [Stage wiki page](http://wiki.ros.org/stage_ros).
- [Question: Simulating a car-like robot in Stage](http://answers.ros.org/question/9470/simulating-a-car-like-robot-in-stage/)
- Checkout how the turtlebot is configured for stage (config files / launch files etc): [Turtlebot in Stage](http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot_stage/Tutorials/indigo/Bring%20up%20TurtleBot%20in%20stage)
- Stage manual: [Robot model](http://playerstage.sourceforge.net/doc/stage-svn/group__model__position.html)
- Stage manual: [Laser model](http://playerstage.sourceforge.net/doc/stage-svn/group__model__laser.html)

If you check out the turtlebot stage package, you will find the turtlebot.inc file (which is loaded from your stage world file):

```
define turtlebot position
(
   pose [ 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 ]
   odom_error [0.03 0.03 999999 999999 999999 0.02]
   size [ 0.2552 0.2552 0.40 ]
   origin [ 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 ]
   gui_nose 1
   drive "diff" # change to "car" for your carlike robot ["diff", "omni" or "car"]
   color "gray"
   kinect(pose [ -0.1 0.0 -0.11 0.0 ]) # replace this with laser / sonar information

   # ADD THE FOLLOWING PARAMETER:
   # only used if drive is set to "car"
   wheelbase 1.0
)
```

You must also define the [wheelbase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheelbase). You might better refer to the example
in the Stage manual (see link above).

After stage is running your model, you need to command the velocity and steering angle.
Here you can chose either your joystick, a predefined control sequence (programmed) or some planner as Orhangazi44
suggested (e.g. [dwa_local_planner](http://wiki.ros.org/dwa_local_planner) or [teb_local_planner](http://wiki.ros.org/teb_local_planner)).

---

Originally posted by [croesmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/12166/croesmann/) with karma: 2531 on 2016-04-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [murdock](https://answers.ros.org/users/26483/murdock/) on 2016-04-04**:
Thank you very much for your information. It was incredibly confusing with all of those tutorials. However, my goal is also to save some data and then visualise it, for example, estimation error plots. Is there any easier way I could do it?

**Comment by [Orhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25268/orhan/) on 2016-04-05**:
Thank You Dear @croesmann. And sorry @murdock, I forgot to write about gazebo simulator. I can simulate turtlebot in Indigo with gazebo simulator. Another simple suggestion; 4. If you are new in ROS, I recommend you to install Indigo. Indigo's EOL date is 2019, (Jade: 2017).

**Comment by [croesmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/12166/croesmann/) on 2016-04-05**:
@murdock regarding saving data and plotting graphs offline you might either take a look at

- python with **numpy** and **pyplot**
- Matlab with **Robotics System Toolbox** (if you are at a university with proper licenses, you might have access to it)
- just plotting: http://wiki.ros.org/rqt_plot

**Comment by [croesmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/12166/croesmann/) on 2016-04-05**:
data can be saved easily using [rosbag](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag) and afterwards replayed using python or matlab. Otherwise you can write and read your data to/from file manually.

**Comment by [murdock](https://answers.ros.org/users/26483/murdock/) on 2016-04-05**:
I see, thank you very much! I have another question regarding AMCL. I am aware that I need to do sensor fusion. This is done by defining a computational model in a matrix. Where does one set these settings in AMCL? Since I havent found src file for AMCL, only a config/header file.

**Comment by [Orhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25268/orhan/) on 2016-04-05**:
Sensor fusion isn't part of an amcl. Take a look at [`robot_localization`](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_localization).

**Comment by [murdock](https://answers.ros.org/users/26483/murdock/) on 2016-04-05**:
Thank you very much!

**Comment by [Orhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25268/orhan/) on 2016-04-05**:
You installed from debian sources, so you haven't got all files. And here is [`amcl_node.cpp`](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/jade-devel/amcl/src/amcl_node.cpp) in jade-devel branch. You can clone and edit all [navigation stack](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/jade).

**Comment by [murdock](https://answers.ros.org/users/26483/murdock/) on 2016-04-05**:
Two more questions. 1. Would I be able to use rosbags with stage?
2. When I do changes to turtlebot.inc, for example, colour, I dont see any changes. Why is it like that?

**Comment by [Orhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25268/orhan/) on 2016-04-06**:
Rosbag is a set of tools for recording from and playing back to ROS topics. I don't understand what you want. How did you install turtlebot? If via `sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-turtlebot-*` like command, try to download to workspace and compile.

**Comment by [Orhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25268/orhan/) on 2016-04-06**:
And please complete all of [this tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials) before working on ROS.

**Comment by [croesmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/12166/croesmann/) on 2016-04-07**:
Regarding your second question about your changes to turtlebot.inc:
Please also check your stage world file. It first includes turtlebot.inc and later spawns the robot.
Some parameters are overwritten there, like color.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

AFAIK, there is no fully working car-like planners in ROS, yet. I have a car-like robot and I'm using [`dwa_local_planner`](http://wiki.ros.org/dwa_local_planner) to avoiding obstacles succesfully. Because My robot needs carefully motions in some narrow places. You can also try [`teb_local_planner`](http://wiki.ros.org/teb_local_planner). It has good tutorials and now supports different footprint types.

---

Originally posted by [Orhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25268/orhan/) with karma: 856 on 2016-04-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [murdock](https://answers.ros.org/users/26483/murdock/) on 2016-04-04**:
Aha, thanks! I am confused what should I try to use in ROS. Should I try using gazebo in which (as far as I understand) I can actually build the "car-like" or just stick with Rviz?

**Comment by [Orhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25268/orhan/) on 2016-04-04**:
You are running `move_base` node in somewhere in .launch files. `move_base`has parameter called **local_planner**, change it to `dwa_local_planner`. Then, dwa planner has a lot of parameters too :) Try to tune it via rqt reconfigure gui (`rosrun rqt_reconfigure rqt_reconfigure` command).

**Comment by [murdock](https://answers.ros.org/users/26483/murdock/) on 2016-04-24**:
@Orhangazi44, Could you give me a hint on which dwa_local_planner params I should focus on to make the robot move like a car? Also, does it change a lot if I already have a robot but its using differential drive and I am trying to simulate it as a car?

**Comment by [Orhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25268/orhan/) on 2016-04-24**:
You can try my parameters in my [question](http://answers.ros.org/question/228818/the-crazy-dwaplannerros-is-confusing-on-global-paths-some-parts/). I was using `sbpl_lattice_planner` with it. Now I'm trying `navfn` with `dwa_local_planner`. Because sbpl planner isn't fully compatible with indigo.

**Comment by [Orhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25268/orhan/) on 2016-04-24**:
[Here is](http://answers.ros.org/question/227122/the-sbpl_lattice_planner-is-extending-path-unnecessarily/) why I'm left `sbpl_lattice_planner` behind. You can also find sbpl planner's indigo fork on same link.

**Comment by [murdock](https://answers.ros.org/users/26483/murdock/) on 2016-04-24**:
Aha, move_base has all its params in yaml files, for ex, costmap_common_params, local_costmap_params, and then theres a param that call "base_local_planner" with value="X/TebLocalPlannerROS" /> So instead of X I should use either teb_local_planner or dwa one? It seems too simple to change one line.

**Comment by [croesmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/12166/croesmann/) on 2016-04-24**:
it is as simple as that. But you might load an extra param yaml file for the local planner config. The local costmap resolution value for TEB should not be too low. Find example params [here](https://github.com/rst-tu-dortmund/teb_local_planner_tutorials). for jackal: diff_drive as starting point

**Comment by [croesmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/12166/croesmann/) on 2016-04-25**:
I added a jackal setup to the tutorials package (see this [branch](https://github.com/rst-tu-dortmund/teb_local_planner_tutorials/tree/jackal_test)). I recommend teb_local_planner version 0.4 which is not yet available on the public repos, but only from source. Parameters are tuned only roughly.